# What is the name of the tune that Black always whistles?

Tags: music, kekkai-sensen

When watching episode 10.5 of Kekkai Sensen, I found that Black, when possessed by King of Despair, was whistling some tune. I'm sure that Black whistles that tune more than once.

I remember hearing it:

- Before Leo [meets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JI-_Hkc3Bc8&t=1) Black in a train, and
- When Black is waiting for White to wake up to ask for taking Leo's eye.

Is it from another song? Or is it an original tune?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but it sounds a bit like the [Overture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oWIK2goT2Ew) from Mozart's opera [*The Magic Flute*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magic_Flute). The same tune seems to play in the [PV for Epi 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fi1HBbbFXo4).

Comment: It is not the Overture.... :(
XD

Comment: [na na na](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4h2gW8Ve91w) Actually sounds quite familiar as well to it.

Comment: Note: having listened to [the Kekkai Sensen soundtrack](http://vgmdb.net/album/52448), I can verify that it is not included there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ep11 seems to suggest that it's Magic Flute's Overture but slowed down.
Well, they did use Ode to Joy as well (Albeit, usage is not as epic as Evan), so I'm assuming that they also selected another classical piece to be in.

In EP 11: 
1659-1723 King of Despair hums that song at an extremely slow pace.
1723-2017 his hum is replaced with orchestra version which seems to increase in speed after a while.

Compare to [1:27](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=h018rMnA0pM#t=85) and set the speed to 0.5. Or a different source at here at [5:38](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fas6zUDa5t8&feature=youtu.be&t=5m35s).

credits to ʞɹɐzǝɹ for bringing 'Overture' up.

man you got me thinking about Hibike Euphonium all over again.

Comment: FYI the first link isn't working anymore.